# CSV String vs Arrays: Is this too stringly typed?

Tags: arrays, string, performance

I came across some existing code in our production environment given to us by our vendor.  They use a string to store comma seperated values to store filtered results from a DB.  Keep in mind that this is for a **proprietary scripting language called PowerOn** that interfaces with a database residing on an AIX system, but it's a language that supports strings, integers, and arrays.

For example, we have;

```
Account
----------------
123
234
3456
28390
```

The psuedo code might look like;

```
Define accounts As String
For Each Account
   accounts=accounts + CharCast(Account) + ","
End
```

as opposed to something I would expect to see like

```
Define accounts As Integer Array(99)
Define index as Integer=0
For Each Account
   accounts(index)=Account
   index=index+1
End
```

By the time the loop is done, `accounts` will look like; `123,234,3456,28390,`.  The string is later used to test if a specific instance exists like so

```
If CharSearch("28390", accounts) > 0 Then Call DoSomething
```

In the example, the statement evaluates to true and `DoSomething` gets called.  **Given the option of arrays, why would want to store integer values whithin a string of comma seperated values?**  Every language I've come across, it's almost always more expensive to perform string based operations than integer based operations.

Considering I haven't seen this technique before and my experience is somewhat limitted, **is there a name for this? Is this common practice or is this just another example of being too stringly typed? To extend the existing code, should I continue using string method?**  Did we get cruddy code from our vendor?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're after.  Searching an integer in text representation within a single piece of contiguous memory can be faster (by using e.g. Boyer-Moore) than iterating over an array, whose internal representation is sometimes laid out as array of pointers to the actual data.

Comment: Well, in maintaining the code, I have option of continuing the string method or to use the array method.  I suppose I'm torn between which to use.

Comment: Implement your `CharSeach(....)` example in the array case.  If it looks easier to maintain to you just go with that.  I don't want to dub it premature optimisation but I think you should always have a *good* (if not *very good*) reason to break with existing conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I put in the comment still holds but my real answer is: It's probably a design decision with respect to compatibility/portability.  In your integer-array case (and a low enough level of the API) you'd typically find yourself asking questions like, what's a safe guess of the size of an integer on "today"'s machines.   What about endianness.

The most portable and most flexible of all data formats always has been and always will be printed representation.  It may not be as fast to process that but that's where adapters/converters or so kick in.  I wouldn't be surprised to find (human-readable) printed representation of something *especially* in database APIs like you describe.

If you want something fast, just take whatever is given to you, convert it to a more efficient internal format, do you processing and convert it back.

Comment: +1 for endianness consideration.  The current envrionment is does consist of multiple platforms (Intel + P5)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing inherently wrong with using comma-separated strings instead of arrays. Sure you can't readily access a random `n`'s element of such a collection, but if such random access is not needed then there's no penalty for it, right?

As far as I know Oracle DB stores `NUMBER` values as strings (and if my memory is correct - for `DATE`s as well) for very practical reasons.

In your specific example looks like using strings is an overkill when dealing with passing data around without crossing the process boundaries. But could it be that the choice of string data type makes more sense when sending data over wire or storing on disk?